# Can I embed navigation controller view to take portion of screen of Custom UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Can I embed navigation controller view to take portion of screen of Custom UIViewController?

I always used navigation controller in full screen but here it will be part of screen 
I tested it and it works, is their unforeseen problems that may happen?

```
------
|UIView|
------
|contentView: UINavigation view|
------
|UIView|
------
```

Answer (score 2):

No issue with this. Just remember that referring to navigationController will always refer to the nav controller that the view is currently in (if you have multiple). I've embedded navigation controllers in custom views many times! Just keep track of what you're referencing!